# Prevent users change of hidden field value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently developing one project and I just discovered that the value of hidden fields can be edited. So that causes me a problem of security. 
Imagine that I have a form to edit personal information. Currently, the form has a hidden input that has the value of the primary key. So if someone change that value can update data from another people.

I already check here and on google and found a possible solution on https://mvcsecurity.codeplex.com/. But unfortunately, that's not available to the recent version of ASP.NET MVC.
So I want to know if someone knows the properly way to prevent that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is, **Never trust data coming from client!**

You should never trust data coming from a client browser. It can be altered by the end user. So don't simply trust the value. **Always do needed validations on server side** to make sure that the data / operation is valid.

In your specific case, When the form is submitted, you should check the value of the hidden field (the primary key value of the record being edited) is valid for the current user to be edited. Depending upon your systems user permissions/role system, you can do some `if` checks and determine whether the current user is authorized to do this operation with the value coming from client.

Comment: So your suggestion is to always validate, at the server, if the current user has permissions to do a specific edition right?

Comment: Yes. **Always validate on server**. Client side validations are usually to prevent a round trip to server/ make end user experience delightful. Never trust data coming from client. Always validate before doing any operations.

Comment: ok. That's great!
If you can give me an opinion may I store the data sent to view in Session to compare or this is bad practice?

Comment: I absolutely agree that you must always validate any data the servers receives from the client.  It's trivial for people to use tools like Postman to post anything they want to your server.

Comment: If you playing around/ trying to learn, It is OK. But please read this [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/)

Comment: is it okay if in the GET method, I use a Session like Session["currentId"] then use it on the POST?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to encrypt the primary key before putting it in the hidden variable.  That's the approach alot of site use, although often the encrypted var will be in the query string.

Comment: Where is the key stored and] how it is shared between the clent and server. Encryoption tends to move a problem.

Comment: @zaph key storage is always a problem and often the weakest link in any encryption approach.  But any common approach will be more secure than passing a primary key unencrypted to the client and then having them pass it back and then blindly trusting that it wasn't tampered with and using it to update a record in a database.

Comment: OK, but this just moves the problem, it does not solve it. Not only  key storage but key sharing are a problem.

Comment: is it okay to just use a Session["id"]?

Comment: @Kokombads - holding the value in session is a very common approach.  The poster however specifically asked about sending the value to the client.

Comment: so sir, that means i could use Session without compromising security?

Comment: Security is a big topic that fills many books, it's not something that can be easily addressed in a comment here on SO.  To make session more secure use SSL for all requests so that the session cookie is not sent over the internet in the clear. This reduces the chance that others can intercept the session cookie and access the session.